# Align multiple choice letter to top of tikzpicture

Tags: vertical-alignment, exam

I desire to have the letter aligned to the top of the figure. I am unsure how to do this. I believe the choices environment is similar to that of an enumerate environment, but I am unsure how to modify that similar.

This is what it looks like:

[image: What it looks like]

This is what I desire:

[image: what I desire]

```tex
\documentclass[%
12pt, 
a4paper,
]{exam}

\newlength{\figsize}
\setlength{\columnsep}{0pt}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{multicol}

\newcommand{\diagram}{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[rounded corners]  (-2.0cm, 5cm) rectangle (5cm,-2.0cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{questions}
        \pointsinmargin\pointformat{}      
        
        \setlength{\figsize}{0.35\textwidth}

        \question[1]%
        Here is a question that fills up some lines.
        
        \begin{multicols}{2}
        \begin{choices}
            \choice \begin{center}\resizebox{\figsize}{!}{\diagram}\end{center}
            \choice \begin{center}\resizebox{\figsize}{!}{\diagram}\end{center}
            \choice \begin{center}\resizebox{\figsize}{!}{\diagram}\end{center}
            \choice \begin{center}\resizebox{\figsize}{!}{\diagram}\end{center}
        \end{choices}
        \end{multicols}
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

p.s. If it's possibly to automatically set \figsize based on the columns - width of the letter `A.`, that would be great, but I can't find any mention of something containing the column width in the multicol documentation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the simplest way to get graphs for each answer choice like in the example below](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/214921/what-is-the-simplest-way-to-get-graphs-for-each-answer-choice-like-in-the-exampl)

Comment: I don't see how that works within the the choices environment of the exam class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `baseline` key to shift the baseline of a `tikzpicture`. In that key you can use `current bounding box` to reference the size of the current picture. And using the `calc` library we can shift that point downwards by the height of the `\strutbox` to get decent looking top alignment compared to the letters.

To set the `\figsize` automatically you can store `M.` inside a box (M is most likely the widest letter of your font), and set the `\figsize` to the current line width minus the width of that box (using `\dimexpr` such things are possible).

Full code:

```
\documentclass[%
12pt, 
a4paper,
]{exam}

\newlength{\figsize}
\setlength{\columnsep}{0pt}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{multicol}

\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\diagram}
  {%
    \setfigsize
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline={($(current bounding box.north)-(0,\ht\strutbox)$)}]
      \draw[rounded corners]  (0,0) rectangle (\figsize,\figsize);
    \end{tikzpicture}%
  }
\newcommand*\setfigsize
  {%
    \sbox0{M.}% M should be the widest letter
    \setlength\figsize{\dimexpr\linewidth-\wd0\relax}%
  }
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \begin{questions}
        \pointsinmargin\pointformat{}      
        
        \setlength{\figsize}{0.35\textwidth}

        \question[1]%
        Here is a question that fills up some lines.
        
        \begin{multicols}{2}
        \begin{choices}
            \choice \begin{center}\diagram\end{center}
            \choice \begin{center}\diagram\end{center}
            \choice \begin{center}\diagram\end{center}
            \choice \begin{center}\diagram\end{center}
        \end{choices}
        \end{multicols}
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to top align an image file you can use `\adjustimage` from the `adjustbox` package instead of `\includegraphics` (note that the `\adjustimage` doesn't use an optional argument but a mandatory one, it supports all the options of `graphicx` plus the `adjustbox` specific ones). If you want to top align something arbitrary (this would also work with a `tikzpicture`) you can use `\adjustbox{valign=t}{<stuff>}`.

Example:

```
\documentclass[%
12pt, 
a4paper,
]{exam}

\newlength{\figsize}
\setlength{\columnsep}{0pt}

\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{multicol}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\diagram}
  {%
    \setfigsize
    \adjustimage{valign=t, width=\figsize}{example-image-duck}%
  }
\newcommand*\setfigsize
  {%
    \sbox0{M.}% M should be the widest letter
    \setlength\figsize{\dimexpr\linewidth-\wd0\relax}%
  }
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \begin{questions}
        \pointsinmargin\pointformat{}      
        
        \setlength{\figsize}{0.35\textwidth}

        \question[1]%
        Here is a question that fills up some lines.
        
        \begin{multicols}{2}
        \begin{choices}
            \choice \begin{center}\diagram\end{center}
            \choice \begin{center}\diagram\end{center}
            \choice \begin{center}\diagram\end{center}
            \choice \begin{center}\diagram\end{center}
            \choice \begin{center}\adjustbox{valign=t}{\rule{10pt}{50pt}}\end{center}
        \end{choices}
        \end{multicols}
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Ah! Thanks.

Is this possible if the exported tikz files have been saved as pdfs and included with `\includegraphics`? Since posting this (of course) I've reached Overleaf's compilation limit, and used [this](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Questions/I_have_a_lot_of_tikz%2C_matlab2tikz_or_pgfplots_figures%2C_so_I%27m_getting_a_compilation_timeout._Can_I_externalise_my_figures%3F#Generating_the_drawings_in_a_separate_project) solution to improve compile times. This means I'm just importing pdfs, and it doesn't seem to work if I just paste the [baseline=...] part in the other project.

Comment: Alternatively - what if I don't have tikz pictures at all, and instead they are all pictures? I believe the same problem would arise.

Comment: @Modelmat `\usepackage{adjustbox}` then use `\adjustimage{valign=t}{<file>}` instead of `\includegraphics{<file>}`.

Comment: @Modelmat see the edit.

Answer (score 1):

A solution with `\vspace{-\baselineskip}`

```
\documentclass[%
12pt, 
a4paper,
]{exam}

\newlength{\figsize}
\setlength{\columnsep}{0pt}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{multicol}

\newcommand{\diagram}{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[rounded corners]  (-2.0cm, 5cm) rectangle (5cm,-2.0cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{questions}
        \pointsinmargin\pointformat{}      
        
        \setlength{\figsize}{0.35\textwidth}

        \question[1]%
        Here is a question that fills up some lines.
        
        \begin{multicols}{2}
        \begin{choices}
            \choice \mbox{}\vspace{-\baselineskip}
            \begin{center}\resizebox{\figsize}{!}{\diagram}\end{center}
            \choice \mbox{}\vspace{-\baselineskip}
            \begin{center}\resizebox{\figsize}{!}{\diagram}\end{center}
            \choice \mbox{}\vspace{-\baselineskip}
            \begin{center}\resizebox{\figsize}{!}{\diagram}\end{center}
            \choice \mbox{}\vspace{-\baselineskip}
            \begin{center}\resizebox{\figsize}{!}{\diagram}\end{center}
        \end{choices}
        \end{multicols}
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This seems to break if I have `\usepackage{enumitem}`. They are not high enough. I need to add `\vspace{-\labelsep}` as well.

Comment: @Modelmat That's right!